# I bought a game on for linux can I install it on windows?

Tags: steam, windows-7, linux

I have bought a cross-platform game over steam and installed it in Linux. Would I have to buy another key to play it on my Windows pc? or could I just install it on my windows pc?

Comment: Have you tried it already?

Comment: no, because I don't yet have access to my windows pc...

Comment: @Renier: Put some effort into solving your problem yourself first. People are more likely to help you if you show that you're capable of helping yourself.

Comment: @MBraedley I can not test it as I do not have access to my windows pc and I googled alot(maybe my key words was wrong), with no luck, I turned to StackExchange for an answer, I could not find the answer on here, so I posted a question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume "cross-platform" refers to [image].

According to [Steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308), you can just install it on windows.

> **What is Steam Play?**
>
> Steam Play allows you to purchase your games once and play anywhere. Whether you have puchased your Steam Play enabled game on a Mac or PC (both Windows and Linux), you will be able to play on the other platform free of charge.

The buy once, play everywhere part is the central part of Steam play.

Comment: So jsut to make sure I understand correctly, if the game is not Steam Play enabled and the game is available on linux and windows, I would have to buy it for both platforms?

Comment: @Renier I assume yes. However, I have just checked the first 10 pages of Linux games on steam, and *all* of them are steam play enabled.

Comment: If the game supports any OS other than windows, then it's SteamPlay enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.
If the game supports [Steam Play](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308) with Linux, you should be able to install the game without rebuying it.
Otherwise, you'll most likely need to rebuy it or run it on a virtual Linux machine.